# Laravel 5.3 Form post error session store not set on request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a public view with a form. To access the form my route is `admin.new_athlete` when I post the form the action calls `admin.create_athlete`
I have this statement in form `{{ csrf_field() }}` just before the first label. This is after the submit button `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token()}}">`

Attached is web.php and controller.
Please advise on the error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you have this route inside web middleware?

Comment: No, because in 5.3 the web.php routes file is already inside middleware.

Comment: So what exactly is your error?

Comment: Exception on Request.php line 882: Session store not set on request when I press the form's submit button.